# Any benefit to Use Finite State Machine with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, state-machine

We already have project which received request on REST EndPoint and by
using FINITE STATE Machine evaluate next action with Transition and
call action class accordingly.

I am assigned to evaluate possibility to migrate this part to apache camel.

But i am not seeing any value addition as in camel we already defined
routes and we can also use dynamic routing for evaluating next
endpoint.

I googled but couldnt find any Apache Camel example using FSM.

I need comments any use case where we can use FSM in Apache Camel or
we dont require due to nature of Camel.

if anyone found any links for google please share it to.

https://dzone.com/articles/why-developers-never-use-state

Regards,

Comment: Apache Camel is a EIP toolkit. It is not a REST services toolkit. So if you are just going to be hosting services on Camel and not using it for integration you will be wasting time.

Comment: what if we have to dynamically pick next integration node on base of FSM?

Comment: Well then you are describing a routing engine. Camel has a routing engine which could do this. However the question does not indicate any need for integration. Are you integrating between different services? Different platforms? Do you need EIP? These things are camel are good at. If you are routing based on state between services internally then Camel is overkill.

Comment: "You are just going to be hosting services on Camel and not using it for integration you will be wasting time" is an extremely ill-advised opinion.